# When and why did Gujarat and Maharashtra separate?

Tags: india

Post-independence, when did these two states actually separate and what was the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two [separated in 1960](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saurashtra_%28region%29#Saurashtra_state). In 1956, under the [States Reorganisation act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_Reorganisation_Act), most states were reorganized along linguistic lines. However, this act actually consolidated Gujarati and Marathi speaking areas together. This led to [agitation in both these regions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarat#Post_independence), and they were separated in 1960.